# Need to find region wise sum of units and their % with respect to the total units

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the table I have

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMjvH.png)

I tried with the below code it erroneous as the select query is not grouped.
Need a solution with co-related sub-query in SQL Server

```
with percentag
as
(
    select region, sum(unit) [Sum of Units] from salesorders 
    group by region
) 
select p.region, p.[Sum of Units], p.[Sum of Units]/sum(s.unit)*100 as percentage1 
from percentag p
join salesorders s on p.region = s.region
```

The expected result should be :

As the total units is 85

| Region | Sum_unit | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East | 25 | 29.411 |
| West | 60 | 71.588 |

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And show us your desired results (as table markdown text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *windowed* form of `sum()` for the denominator by replacing `sum(s.unit)` with `sum(p.[Sum of Units]) over()`. The empty `over()` qualifier (with no partition-by, order-by, or rows specification) sets the scope (window) of the sum to be the entire result set.

The extra `salesorders` join should be dropped, as it is no longer needed.

Also, you need to move the 100 multiplier to the front of the expression and change it to a `float` or `decimal` constant to avoid a zero result from the integer division.

The resulting query would be something like:

```
with region_sums as
(
    select region, sum(unit) Sum_unit
    from salesorders 
    group by region
) 
select
    rs.region,
    rs.Sum_unit,
    100e0 * rs.Sum_unit / sum(rs.Sum_unit) over() as Percentage 
from region_sums rs
```

The CTE can also be a subselect as follows:

```
select
    rs.region,
    rs.Sum_unit,
    100e0 * rs.Sum_unit / sum(rs.Sum_unit) over() as Percentage 
from (
    select s.region, sum(s.unit) Sum_unit
    from salesorders s
    group by s.region
) rs
```

The CTE or subselect can be eliminated and the group-by applied at the outer level. In this case, the overall total is calculated by nesting the group-by sum inside the windowed sum.

```
select
    s.region,
    sum(s.unit) Sum_unit,
    100e0 * sum(s.unit) / sum(sum(s.unit)) over() as Percentage
from salesorders s
group by s.region
```

This simplifies the overall query, but might be more difficult for someone maintaining the code to read and understand later.

All produce the same results:

| region | Sum of Units | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East | 25 | 29.4117647058824 |
| West | 60 | 70.5882352941177 |

You can add rounding logic if needed.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lXrJUSfj) for a demo showing all three forms of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the window function as follows:

```
select s.region, 
       sum(s.unit) as sum_unit, 
       (sum(s.unit)/sum(sum(s.unit)) over (partition by s.region)) *100 as percentage1 
from salesorders s
group by s.region;
```

Comment: It gives the percentage1 = 0 for both records, guess because its grouped by region

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: It now gives the percentage1 = 100, The total units is 85 and for the East region its 25, so the percentage of east region should be (25/85)*100 = 29 % and for west region it should be = 70 %

Comment: You need to convert either the numerator or the denominator to a decimal value before the division. That's why you're getting results that are truncated downward. Look into "integer division".